# Lenovo Windows XP Reinstall Driver help

Tags: windows, drivers, reinstall

I'm reinstalling Windows on an IBM Thinkpad T43. (Not T43p) I reinstalled the OS and now there a number of drivers that I need to reinstall. Any help would be appreciated. I've been to Lenovo's website. This would be a breeze but the Device Manager lists 2 Unknown devices. How do I figure out what those are?

Comment: What doesn't work?  There's your answer.

Answer (score 1):

See the [MS support article](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/314464) on troubleshooting unknown devices.

As a ThinkPad user, I'd recommend installing **all drivers provided by Lenovo**. Even though the default XP drivers may work, some functionality only works with Lenovo drivers.

One example is [ActiveProtection](http://www.pc.ibm.com/us/think/thinkvantagetech/aps.html), another are the 3 TrackPoint buttons on some models. Neither would show up as Unknown Device, but the functionality would be missing without Lenovo drivers.

On the other hand, wireless/update/management software by Lenovo is not so good, I always skip it.

Answer (score 1):

You can download compressed drivers from driverpacks.net and create a driver cd for installation. It will install nearly 98% of missing drivers: see instructions here : ["Solution: Find, Install Windows XP Drivers Easily"](http://www.computing-tips.net/Solved_Find_Install_Windows_XP_Drivers_Easily/)

Answer (score 0):

what you need to do is find the hardware ID of the device (should be in the properties of the unknown devices) with this you can post it here or do a search with JUST that information in Google and it should point to which device it is. take a look around google is a great tool.

Good Luck!!

Answer (score -1):

Maybe a third party app like [devicedoctor](http://www.devicedoctor.com/) or [drivermax](http://www.drivermax.com/) can help you?

Device Doctor is a:

> freeware Windows application that scans your computer hardware and checks to see if there are new driver updates available for your devices. It also locates drivers for "unidentified devices" in the Windows Device Manager.

Driver max:

> allows you to download the latest driver updates for your computer. No more searching for some rare driver on discs or on the web. No more driver CD after the other. Just create a free account, log in, and start downloading the driver updates that you need.

Comment: Warning: the "driver helper" category of programs often comes with **malware** (viruses, spyware, rootkits) bundled. This is particularly dangerous since drivers run at highest privilege. If Microsoft did not include a driver in their database/update mechanism, that may be for a good reason. I do not know specifically if devicedoctor or drivermax are ok or not.

Comment: Fair point, well made. I'm fairly confident that these two are OK, but yeah, take all suitable precautions.